# How to solve the error in the matrix during execution?

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, matrices

The goal is to place a matrix and its corresponding figure side by side
I'm using egreg's answer @egreg

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{a-matrix}
CM'=
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[
  first-row,code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle,
  first-col,code-for-first-col=\scriptstyle,
]
                   & 1                  & \mathcolor{red}{3}      & 4 \\
1                  & 1                  & \mathcolor{red}{x_{13}} & x_{12}x_{24} \\
\mathcolor{red}{3} & \mathcolor{red}{0} & \mathcolor{red}{1}      & \mathcolor{red}{x_{34}} \\   
4                  & 0                  & \mathcolor{red}{0}      & 1  
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

The advice was to update the latex package, but after updating, the same error appears. (When executed I get an error message:"\l__nicematrix_last_col_in... l.17 ] The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., \hobx'), type I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about " )

[image]

Note that I am using a latex package on Windows 11. After several attempts, I discovered the error due to the way the matrix was written. When replaced with another equation, the code works.

```
\begin{equation}\label{a-matrix}
    CM'=
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[
      first-row,code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle,
      first-col,code-for-first-col=\scriptstyle,
    ]
                       & 1                  & \mathcolor{red}{3}      & 4 \\
    1                  & 1                  & \mathcolor{red}{x_{13}} & x_{12}x_{24} \\
    \mathcolor{red}{3} & \mathcolor{red}{0} & \mathcolor{red}{1}      & \mathcolor{red}{x_{34}} \\   
    4                  & 0                  & \mathcolor{red}{0}      & 1  
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
    \end{equation}
```

[image]
Is there a solution to this error or another way to write the matrix so that we can overcome the error in implementation?

Comment: The last version of nicematrix is 6.26d. For me it's work fine.

Comment: You claim an error about something related to `nicematrix`, but your picture shows `\kbordermatix`.

Comment: @egreg the same error. I update the picture

Comment: the same version @pascal974

Comment: Please trim your first code down to a minimal example that still shows the error, and expand your second code to be a complete example that doesn't show the error.  Saying that the error is "due to the way the matrix was written" and "When replaced with another equation, the code works." isn't all that helpful.  What change did you make?

Comment: @Teepeemm I updated the question

Comment: You didn't update your TeX system properly.